# proceeding to next id from model php

Tags: php, object, models

Hi I'll post the code in question first then ask the question(s).

```
function printUserActiveAds($currUser){
        $activeUser = new users();
        $userActiveAds = new userAds();

        echo
        '
            <h4>Currently Active Ads:</h4>
            <table class="userActiveAds">
                <tr><td>Title</td><td></td><td>Price</td><td></td><td>Description</td><td></td><td>Delete</td></tr>
        ';

        $numAds = $userActiveAds->getNumberOfAdsByUserId($currUser);
        if($numAds > 0){
            for($i = 0; $i < $numAds; $i++){
                $id = $userActiveAds->getAdIdByUserId($currUser);
                echo
                '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$userActiveAds->getAdTitleById($id).'</td><td></td>
                        <td>'.$userActiveAds->getAdPriceById($id).'</td><td></td>
                        <td>'.truncateDescription($userActiveAds->getAdDescriptionById($id),100).'</td><td></td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" class="button" value="Delete" />
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ';
                    }
        }else{
            echo
            '
                <tr><td colspan="7"><span class="prompt">Currently No Active Ads</span></td></tr>
            ';
        }
```

Model (userAds)

```
//ad model
    class userAds {
        private $id;
        private $title;
        private $price;
        private $location;
        private $category;
        private $subCategory;
        private $description;

        //default constructor
        function _constructor(){
            $this->id = null;
            $this->title = null;
            $this->price = null;
            $this->location = null;
            $this->category = null;
            $this->subCategory = null;
            $this->description = null;
        }

        //set the ad details
        function setAdDetails($adId,$adTitle, $adPrice, $adLocation, $adCategory, $adSubCategory, $adDescription){
            $this->id = $adId;
            $this->title = $adTitle;
            $this->price = $adPrice;
            $this->location = $adLocation;
            $this->category = $adCategory;
            $this->subCategory = $adSubCategory;
            $this->description = $adDescription;
        }

        //get number of ads by user using user id
        function getNumberOfAdsByUserId($userId){
            $numberOfAds = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE user_id='$userId'") or die(mysql_error());
            return $numAds = mysql_num_rows($numberOfAds);
        }

        //get ad id by user id
        function getAdIdByUserId($userId){
            $queryAdId = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ads WHERE user_id='$userId'") or die(mysql_error());
            $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryAdId);
            return $this->id = $data['id'];
        }
```

Ok so the specific piece of code in quesiont is getAdIdByUserId. It doesn't iterate over all the ids associated with a specific user. Bassically what I wanted to was to take all the ads asssociated with a particular user and display in a table. However when I run the code above I get the correct number of ads associated with that user but the table only displays the first id associated with that user. I was think maybe I should just increment id but the issue there is that this user has ads with id 1,2,3,7, and 17. Any ideas of how to go about this? Also as you can see from the printActiveAds function I created two objects, the other question I have is do I have to delete them at the end of the function or I shouldn't worry about them because they are removed once the function is done (local scope).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the issue. I was missing set statements and basic get statements. I did mysql_fetch_array($query) after I did a query, and then set each row equal to a userAd property and then when I did echo I called what I set